dpdk 21.11 How to setup TSO hardware offload? What are the steps?
I want to know how to set hardware TSO in dpdk21.11 version, not software gso. It is divided into several steps, or the official website which has a code example? thanks.
How to set up TSO hardware offload.
Steps to set up.
It would be nice to have code examples.

Assuming the task is to enable non-tunnel TSO, approximate workflow should be as follows.

Upon the first invocation of  rte_eth_dev_configure(), invoke rte_eth_dev_info_get() and check whether flag RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO is indicated in fields tx_offload_capa and tx_queue_offload_capa. Also check the same for flags RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM and RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_CKSUM.
If flag RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO is only indicated by tx_offload_capa, invoke rte_eth_dev_configure() again (re-configure, that is) with flag RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO set in eth_conf->txmode.offloads. Some devices may require this flag to be accompanied by the two checksum offload flags (see above). If this is the case, set such in eth_conf->txmode.offloads, too. Then proceed with Tx queue setup, as per usual. But if the TSO flag is also indicated in tx_queue_offload_capa field of the above "device info" response, skip the additional invocation of rte_eth_dev_configure, proceed with rte_eth_tx_queue_setup() and make sure to explicitly set flag RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO (and perhaps the checksum offload flags, too) in tx_conf->offloads.
Upon successful device start, given, for instance, an IPv4 TCP packet mbuf m, set RTE_MBUF_F_TX_IPV4 | RTE_MBUF_F_TX_IP_CKSUM | RTE_MBUF_F_TX_TCP_SEG in m->ol_flags and set m->tso_segsz to the desired TSO MSS value. In order to check whether the mbuf is prepared correctly, invoke rte_validate_tx_offload() on it. Then invoke rte_eth_tx_prepare() on it and, finally, pass it to rte_eth_tx_burst().

Please note, however, that, in order to be able to use segmented mbufs, the driver should indicate flag RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS in its capabilities and it may be required to set the flag when configuring device/queue.

I'm sorry, but I didn't quite understand what you meant in the second step. You mean RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO is set only in tx_offload_capa in rte_eth_dev_info, so I need to call rte_eth_dev_configure again to set RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO for tx_offload_capa. Is that what it means?
